# Removing duplicate item in a list in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to remove duplicate items in a list that is retrieved from a mysql database.

After running my query to find the cities that leave from a certain destination i use the following code to store and display my list.

```
    while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $City = $dbRow['Destination_City'];        
       $items = explode(',', $City);

       echo "<ul>\n";

       foreach( $items as $item )
       {
         echo "<li>$City</li>\n";
       }

       echo "</ul>";
```

I tried using `array_unique` but i can't get it too work.

Comment: Why do you query duplicates at first?

Comment: In my database there is duplicates of some cities that leave from the same destination, but use different airlines. For this part i have the destinations being displayed, but want to display only one version of the city.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting your mysql data with 'DISTINCT' as it only returns 1 of each in a column(no duplicates).

```
$dbQuery =  $con->query("SELECT DISTINCT 'column' FROM 'table'");
```

Also would you mind putting up your array_unique code because I'm not sure why it wouldn't work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

array_unique should work, like this:

```
$cities = array();
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $cities[] = $dbRow['Destination_City'];
}
$cities = array_unique($cities);

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach( $cities as $city )
{
    echo "<li>$city</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: He should probably echo $item, not $City

Comment: @OUDK now you're supposed to click on the "up arrow" about the 0 to give me props ;-)

Comment: @BrianAnderson Haven't reached the required 15 reputation yet so am unable to, but thank you for your help!

Comment: ^^ ouch. I got two haha

Comment: One of yours came from me, @IanThompson. That is a much better solution, but if he can't do that, then this should work.